# what is the minimum android os level for fused location provider

Tags: java, android, gps, location

what is the minimum compatible version for android operating system if I want to use fused location provider to get current location ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a minimum version.
Even and if you use SDK:10 it will work.
http://web.archive.org/web/20141216140051/https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html

and an example
https://web.archive.org/web/20130911205013/http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html

Answer (score 4):

The Fused Location Provider requires Google Play Services to be available on a device. Since the release on [Play Services 4.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) , the `minVersionSdk` is set to `9`, the equivalent of Android 2.3.

In theory you can use the Fused Location Provider on Android 2.2 too, but you'll need to resort to the no-longer-updated Froyo version of the Google Play Services SDK. It's a year old now, so not ideal.

Personally, I couldn't be bothered supporting Android 2.2 any longer, as it has an almost negligible number of users these days ([~0.7%](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html))